# Core Animation: raster not animating

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-animation

I am trying to perform a quick and dirty "blur" by applying a raster to a CALayer. The CA documentation says that shouldRasterize is animatable however I am not getting any animation. Code below:

```
 CABasicAnimation* blurAnimation;
 blurAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"rasterize"];
 blurAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
 blurAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
 blurAnimation.duration = 3.0f;
 blurAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];    
 blurAnimation.repeatCount = 20; // HUGE_VALF;
blurAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3f];
blurAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
[theCheck setShouldRasterize:YES];

 // Add animation to the layer and make it so
 [theCheck addAnimation:blurAnimation forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to change "rasterize" to "rasterizationScale"?